# Create config collector for exposing config settings accross application

Tags: symfony

I'm looking for way of exposing config settings across application, where I can in any bundle add what I want. Purpose of this is to expose several things to HTML, parse it and use in JS.

Base part is `ConfigService` to which can be added `ConfigUnit` with own logic.

ConfigServiceInterface:

```
public function getConfig();
public function addUnit(ConfigUnitInterface $unit);
```

ConfigUnitInterface:

```
public function getName();
public function getConfig();
```

best would be to add units in `service.yml` like this:

```
services:
  service.config:
    class: ConfigService
    calls:
      - [ addUnit, [ "@unit" ] ]
      - [ addUnit, [ "@unit2" ] ]
```

but config service should be declared in some bundle and developer can't change it's declaration.

second thing which comes to my mind was declare units with calling register method which would get `ConfigService` as parameter.

```
config_unit:
    class: ConfigUnit
    arguments: [...]
    calls:
      - [ register, [ "@service.config" ] ]
```

but this isn't nice and I must get this service to init calls, so I must get it from container each time.

Is there way to do this automatically? And separate as possible?

Maybe event would be nice for this, but I don't want to allow developer to modify config array directly.

Comment: I tried to get the point but its really not clear to me. Who is the user? A developer using the framework? Can you put your example in a more clear way? Sorry for asking this but I tried to read twice and didn't understand what you want exactly!

Comment: Yes I mean developer "sry" (edited). Purpose is to have somewhere in vendor bundle with ConfigService and other bundles depending on this. This bundles are adding their units to this ConfigService. And somewhere in application is developer getting final config array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found out how to do it.

documentation helps:

[tags](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/tags.html), [compiler pass](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/compiler_passes.html)

Each my unit has now tag: 'config.unit'

```
config_unit:
  class: ConfigUnit
  arguments: [...]
  tags:
    -  { name: config.unit }
```

these are processed by `CompilerPass` and injected to `ConfigService`